# how to give subnets for IP addresses in rewrite condition?

Tags: rewritecond

I want to give subnet for various IPs while writing rewritecond. So how should i give the subnet mask in the below rule. the IP is 218.104.51.160/29

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-For} !^IP
RewriteRule ^  - [F,L]
```

Comment: Rather than asking for help implementing a specific solution to your problem, tell us what your problem is. Why do you want to do this? What problem will it solve?

Answer (score 3):

You can't. What you're trying to do makes no sense.